# How to get the full table html from Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get the table html in Jquery.

I have the following:

```
<table id='table' border='1'>
<tr><td>items...</td><td>items2...</td></tr>
<tr><td>items...</td><td>items2...</td></tr>
<tr><td>items...</td><td>items2...</td></tr>
<tr><td>items...</td><td>items2...</td></tr>
</table>
```

I have

```
var test = $('#table').html()
```

but when i console.log(test) i got

```
<tr><td>items...</td><td>items2...</td></tr>
<tr><td>items...</td><td>items2...</td></tr>
<tr><td>items...</td><td>items2...</td></tr>
<tr><td>items...</td><td>items2...</td></tr>
```

without `<table>` tags.

Is there anyway to fix this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: .html() only retrieve the contects with-in the specified tag.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A more jQuery oriented approach would be to retrieve the outerHtml property from the table.

```
 $('#table').prop('outerHTML')
```

Comment: Nice, I'd never considered that approach! :)

Comment: Will this work on older browsers?

Comment: @Blazemonger, I can't confirm it at the moment, but outerHtml() is a well supported JavaScript function.

Answer (score 3):

One option is:

```
document.getElementById('table').outerHTML;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/neBSy/1/).

Or, you could instead:

```
$('<div />').html($('#table').clone()).html();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/neBSy/).

Comment: +1 for not using jQuery if it isn't necessary. If you'd like to use it in jQuery:

`var table = document.getElementById('table').outerHTML;`
`var jqueryTable = $(table);`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to wrap the table in something else, then get the html() of that element instead.

Example Markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <table id='table' border='1'>
        <tr><td>items...</td><td>items2...</td></tr>
        <tr><td>items...</td><td>items2...</td></tr>
        <tr><td>items...</td><td>items2...</td></tr>
        <tr><td>items...</td><td>items2...</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
var table = $('.wrapper').html();
```

You should probably just use @David Thomas' answer though.